# Object Required Error when trying to use a Sub to Pass Values to a User Defined Function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user defined function I would like a sub to use. The UDF works fine, but I need the process to be dynamic; so really I need a sub that will pass two arguments in to my UDF. I keep getting an "object required" error when I try to run the sub. Below is the code for the sub:

```
Sub pbPeriod()

Dim outF As Long
Dim inF As Range

Set outF = Range("InvestmentOutlay").Value
Set inF = Range(Range("B55"), Range("B55").End(xlToRight))
Range("PB").Formula = "=PaybackPeriod(" & outF.Address & ", " & inF.Address & ")"

End Sub
```

When I debug it highlights "Set outF= ", but I'm not sure what is actually happening. I'll post the UDF below, but really it accepts two arguments and is used to find payback period. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you:

```
Public Function PayBackPeriod(outlay, inflow)
    Dim i, yr As Integer
    Dim cTotal As Double ' cumulative total
    cTotal = 0

        For i = 1 To inflow.Count
        cTotal = cTotal + inflow.Cells(i).Value

        If cTotal = Abs(outlay) Then
        PayBackPeriod = i
        Exit Function
        End If
        If cTotal > Abs(outlay) Then
         yr = i - 1
         cTotal = cTotal - inflow.Cells(i).Value
         PayBackPeriod = yr + (Abs(outlay) - (cTotal)) / inflow.Cells(i).Value

         Exit Function

        End If
        Next i
        PayBackPeriod = "Not enough return to Payback!!!"
```

Comment: Ditch the `Set` as it is not an object variable. It would be good practice to declare the type of arguments in your function. It looks like you are passing strings but that is not going to work in your function. Keep spotting new things - outF is declared as Long so does not have an address property - perhaps you meant to declare as range too (in which case Set would be required).

Comment: @SJR Thanks for taking a look. So, I'll attempt to clarify, I'm super new at this so forgive me if its not what you're looking for. I declared 'outF' as Long because it's a single number being passed in to the function. Should I be using 'Range' in that instance? Also, in terms of passing strings through the function, I'm not really sure how else to do it...If I drop the 'Set' from in front of 'outF' I get an invalid qualifier error where my code says "outF.Address".

Comment: You don't need my forgiveness! Problem is that, e.g. trying to calculate the `Abs` of a string won't work. Looks like you want to pass a range in both cases. Or you could use `abs(range(outlay))`.

Comment: @ SJR I just tried your suggestion, but then it seems the function doesn't work. Is there another way to write how I'm passing the arguments to the function "Range("PB").Formula = "=PaybackPeriod(" & outF.Address & ", " & inF.Address & ")""? I really appreciate your help, thanks so much.

Comment: My apologies, you do need to pass the address as I forgot you are placing this in the sheet so your original set up was fine. Just declare `outF` as Range and remove the `.value` when you set the variable.

Comment: @ SJR, I can't thank you enough. I can get it to run through without error. Its pulling the wrong cell for outF, but I think I can probably figure that out. Thanks so much for your time, know that I really appreciate it!

Comment: My pleasure, glad it works.